# Does Steam share DLC for games both accounts own?

Tags: steam

The current humble bundle with borderlands 2 contains some dlc, one of which is not in the GOTY edition (which is active on account2)(ultimate vault hunter pack 2), but is missing a lot other DLC (eg. dragon keep). If I decide to activate the base game + UVHP2 on account1, will I still have access to the GOTY DLC? Will account2 have access to the new DLC?
I know there were some issues with this some time ago; did valve do something about that problem yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If account1 has access to the GOTY DLC already, you will not have access to the GOTY DLC on account1 once you activate the base game on account1. Account2 will not have access to the new DLC if account2 is the account sharing the base game. On http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing, it says:

[image]

So, unfortunately, it looks like you cannot share DLC if the account that is being shared to has the base game or activates the base game.